Can we get CTRL-Z (CTRL+Z; Undo) to work properly in an MS Access multiline Rich Text textbox?
In MS Access 2016, I have a bound multiline Rich Text textbox (tbxNote).  Not surprisingly, users press CTRL+Z, expecting that doing so will Undo the last change they made to the text in the textbox.  What happens is that the last change is undone, but if they press CTRL+Z a second time, all changes to the note are undone rather than incrementally moving back in time through changes to the note.  This return to the original content when the textbox was first populated can be devastating if lots of updates to the text were made.  Once CTRL+Z is pressed twice, there is no way (that I know of) to get back the changes that were unexpectedly discarded.
To try to prevent the problems with pressing CTRL+Z twice, I have tried to add code to either the textbox or the form's KeyDown event to try to allow CTRL+Z to be pressed only once and then to ignore future presses.  Oddly, while the code appears to undo the last change on the first CTRL+Z press and to ignore the second CTRL+Z press, in fact, when the record is saved after pressing CTRL+Z once (or twice or however many times) all changes are lost even though the visible text contained the changes prior to saving the textbox note (even though we apparently ignored/canceled the second press).
Here is code in the form's KeyDown event (my testing showed that CTRL+Z was caught first in the form's event) that is behaving oddly as described above (i.e., appears to accept and properly process 1 CTRL+Z press and appears to ignore subsequent CTRL+Z presses, but functionally results in all changes being lost after any CTRL+Z press regardless of what text actually appears in the textbox):
If Shift = acCtrlMask And KeyCode = vbKeyZ Then
    If TempVars!booCtrlZ = False Then
        'do not process this CTRL+Z if we've already pressed it once
        KeyCode = 0  'clear the keypress
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'process the CTRL+Z and flag that it's been pressed once
        TempVars!booCtrlZ = True  'flag that we've pressed CTRL+Z once
    End If
End If

My fundamental goal is to either:

Get CTRL+Z to work as it does in, say, MS Word whereby each CTRL+Z incrementally moves back through changes to the note.
If #1 is not possible, allow 1 CTRL+Z to undo the most recent change and then prevent subsequent CTRL+Z presses.


Interesting question. 1. is impossible - Access only has 2 states of "Undo": a) all changes you made to a control since starting to edit it, b) all changes to the current record.

Some notes: 1. be aware that TempVars are global. So you need to set booCtrlZ to False when entering the control. (probably not the issue here) --- 2. The "regular" undo key for old-time Access users is Esc, not Ctrl+Z.

The behavior is not odd - it is normal for Access. Option 1 is certainly not possible and you have demonstrated that option 2 fails. My only suggestion it to prevent any use of Ctrl+Z and force users to type all changes. This can be done with AutoKeys macro to completely disable Ctrl+Z. I have tested and works.

I tried your code and form's KeyDown event is not triggered.

@Andre, thanks for confirming what I suspected--#1 is not possible.  Sad.  As for TempVars, I appreciate the warning and have taken steps to reset the TempVar at an appropriate point when needed.  As for the Esc key, that was even worse for users because they would press it and all changes would disappear immediately and unexpectedly with no recourse.  I trap Esc and cancel it to prevent this behavior that most users find unexpected (except for ld-timers!).

@June7, thank you for confirming the impossibility of Option 1.  That was my sad suspicion.  Yes, I know how to prevent Ctrl+Z altogether, and that will probably be what I have to do, but it is sad that the 1 apparent use of Ctrl+Z cannot be saved because if a user accidentally deletes an entire multiline note made up of 50 sentences or more (e.g., accidentally selecting the entire text content and typing delete or a character), there will be an outcry.  Alas.  Apparently that is as it must be.

@June7, I'm not sure why the form's KeyDown event is not triggered for you.  I assume you put the code in a form's KeyDown event.  I can confirm that with that code in my form, the code is definitely triggered because when testing code, I put debug.print code in to output to the immediate window and I've also put in MsgBox code to verify that the code is getting executed.  Perhaps it is not triggered for your form based on the Key Preview setting of the form?  I have Key Preview set to "Yes".

As for the idea that the behavior is not "odd"--tell that to every user of the database!  It is definitely not what they expect when they are editing multiline RichText textbox text since it feels like they are using MS Word where they can press CTRL+Z over and over again to progressively undo changes.  I think it is not unreasonable for them to expect it to work similarly in the database--but since the unexpected results can be very sad and dramatic in some cases, it seems important to handle the use of CTRL+Z nicely so the user doesn't hate the programmer.

If you think about it, the algorithm behind a step-by-step Undo isn't trivial. And Word/Outlook don't always get it right as well, either undoing "too much" or "too little". Nevertheless... one might go about it like this: set up a Form_Timer event that watches the textbox text. If there is no change for e.g. 1-2 seconds, create an in-memory snapshot of the text (e.g. in an array or collection). Then you could do your own Undo, going back snapshot after snapshot.

BTW, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432584/enable-redo-for-ms-access-rich-text-fields

@Andre, you are right: the algorithm for Undo is not trivial! Thanks for the link to the related item--I had looked at that but hoped there was something we could do to get Undo to work even if Redo wasn't working. But, it looks like I'll have to take a do-it-myself approach to handling CTRL+Z (and I'll have to implement CTRL+Y as well) because of the outcry by the users. I am sympathetic with the users since these are very long notes they are required to type, so, I think the effort to implement Undo/Redo will be valuable.  I'll post code if I get it working and it's not too complex.

So, I've spent the last several days trying to do it myself.  If anyone has a better approach, I'd love to see it, or, if anyone improves on the approach below, please post here.
Caveats: USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!  THERE IS THE POSSIBILITY TO LOSE DATA.  YOU SHOULD CHECK THE FUNCTIONALITY OF THIS CODE EXTENSIVELY IN YOUR OWN USE SCENARIO BEFORE IMPLEMENTING IT ON LIVE DATA.  I TAKE NO RESPONSIBILITY FOR ANY LOSS YOU MAY INCUR BY THE USE OF THE CODE BELOW.  THERE ARE NO GUARANTEES.  USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
Instructions:

This do-it-yourself implementation may not function exactly the same way as Undo and Redo work in MS Word, but I think it is far better than the exceedingly limited and unexpected functionality of CTRL+Z (undo) that is the default in MS Access
The code below has not been optimized, so there may well be ways of making the code more efficient.
The code below has been tested some in my use scenario, but it has not been used for an extended time so there may be bugs or scenarios that I have not anticipated and will need to be resolved when they are discovered.
The code below will only work properly for one textbox on a form. If you have more than 1 textbox on a form that needs to have undo functionality, you'll need to set up additional collections and additional subs to handle the additional textboxes so that the values from textbox1 aren't implemented into textbox2 with unwanted results.
The code below assumes the name of the textbox that will have the undo/redo functionality is "tbxNote".  In your code, change all references to tbxNote to match the name of your textbox.
I have not included any error handling code, so you can add it yourself using your preferred approach.
You need to have some understanding of VBA coding to ensure that you can implement this code to work for your use scenario.  While the concepts here are not particularly advanced, there are a lot of "moving parts" that must work together to have undo and redo functions that work the way you or your users expect.
Determine when the Undo list should be cleared and then add a call to UndoListClear in all of the events that you determine should clear the Undo list.  Times to consider clearing the UndoList (or else unexpected and unwanted changes to a subsequent textbox could occur!):

When the content of the textbox is finalized/saved by the user, e.g., by leaving the textbox, clicking a save button, or other instances when the data has been committed to the database table.
When the form containing the textbox is opened (Form_Open) to be sure you don't have any undo text items from a previous instance.
When a different record is selected in the form containing the textbox (Form_Current) since the undo items from the previous record will not be appropriate to apply to the current record.
When the form containing the textbox is closed (Form_Close) to clear up the memory used by the collection of values.
NOTE:  The UndoListClear will clear both the undo and the redo lists.


Determine what actions and events should trigger saving an undo list entry and add a call to UndoListUpdate in all of those events.
Determine the maximum number of items the undo list and redo list should contain and adjust the intMaxListCount value in the UndoListClear sub so that it matches your maximum list size.  The code below uses a maximum of 50 items for both the undo list and the redo list.
In the sample code below, CTRL+Z triggers an Undo action.  CTRL+Y and CTRL+SHIFT+Z both trigger a Redo action.
Redo is used if the user changes their mind about an undo action--Redo is basically a way to undo the undo action.
NOTE:  Each text item saved in the undo and redo collection contains 3 parts: the selection start, the selection length, and the text.  The selection start is always 5 characters long, then a comma, then the selection length is always another 5 characters, then a | character, and then the actual undo text to be remembered.  For example:  "00005,00002|This is the text in my textbox." indicates that the cursor selection should start at position 5 and is 2 characters long (i.e., select the word "is") and the text to remember is "This is the text in my textbox."
NOTE:  Because the selection start and length are stored at the beginning of each undo/redo text item, to check what the actual stored text is requires starting 13 characters into the undo/redo item, e.g., Mid(strUndoList(1), 13) to detect the actual text stored in item 1 of the collection

Here's the code:
Private strUndoList As New Collection  'this stores incremental changes to the textbox text
Private strRedoList As New Collection  'this stores each strUndoList item that was undone in case the user presses CTRL+Y or CTRL+SHIFT+Z to undo the undo (i.e., to Redo!)
Private intMaxListCount As Integer  'this value is set in the UndoListClear sub; it is the maximum number of items permitted in the undo and redo lists; when a list exceeds this number of items, the first item in the list will be deleted and all subsequent items will be moved 1 spot toward the front of the list

Private Sub Form_Close()
    'clear out the string collections to free up memory
    UndoListClear
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    'this is triggered when the Record is changed to a different Record, so, we need to clear the Undo list since the Undo values apply to a different note record
    UndoListClear
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If Shift = acCtrlMask And (KeyCode = vbKeyV Or KeyCode = vbKeyX) Then  'add to the UndoList prior to pasting or cutting text from the note control
        If Me.ActiveControl.Name = "tbxNote" Then  'only make an Undo item if we are in the note textbox
            UndoListUpdate
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    UndoListClear  'clear the Undo list
End Sub

Private Sub tbxNote_AfterUpdate()
    'clear the Undo list (and Redo list) on the note since when the note is updated/saved, the user should no longer expect to Undo/Redo
    UndoListClear
End Sub

Private Sub tbxNote_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    'if the user switches to a different control, save the content of the note in the Undo list 
    'in case validation prevents updating/saving the content and the user may then want to use undo/redo functionality
    UndoListUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub tbxNote_Enter()
    'when the user enters the note, store the original text in the Undo list
    UndoListUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub tbxNote_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    'handle CTRL+Z (CTRL-Z) Undo
    If KeyCode = vbKeyZ And Shift = acCtrlMask Then
        KeyCode = 0  'always clear the keypress to prevent the crazy CTRL+Z (undo) behavior of Access
        UndoIt
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'handle CTRL+Y (CTRL-Y) or CTRL+SHIFT+Z Redo
    If (KeyCode = vbKeyY And Shift = acCtrlMask) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyZ And Shift = acCtrlMask + acShiftMask) Then
        KeyCode = 0  'always clear the keypress
        RedoIt
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbxNote_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    'handle updating the undo list when certain keys are pressed, if the note textbox has focus
    'this is done in the KeyUp event rather than the KeyDown event so that if the user is holding down a key (e.g., cursor keys), the Undo list is only updated once instead of repeatedly as would occur if it were in the KeyDown event
    'check if the note textbox control has focus
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name = "tbxNote" Then  'only manage Undo list items if the note textbox has the focus
        Select Case KeyCode
            Case vbKeyReturn, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyHome, vbKeyEnd, vbKeyDelete, vbKeyBack, Asc(".")
                UndoListUpdate
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbxNote_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    'when the mouse is clicked in the note textbox, add the existing text of the note to the Undo list
    UndoListUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub UndoListClear()
    'this sub will clear the undo list of all content
    intMaxListCount = 50  'this sets the maximum size of the Undo and Redo lists; it is used in the UndoListUpdate, UndoIt, and RedoIt subs
    
    If strUndoList.count > 0 Then
        Set strUndoList = New Collection  'clears all items from the old collection by setting it to a new empty collection
    End If
    If strRedoList.count > 0 Then
        Set strRedoList = New Collection  'clears all items from the old collection by setting it to a new empty collection
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UndoListUpdate()
    'this sub will add an item to the undo list collection
    'NOTE: must work with .Text, not .Value since .Value is not updated when the user types, but .Text is
    'if this was called from a button, then the .Text value will not be accessible
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name <> "tbxNote" Then Exit Sub  'we cannot process the .Text value of the note textbox control if the textbox does not have the focus
    
    If strUndoList.count > 0 Then  'if there is already an item in the list, check to make sure we are not adding the same text twice in a row to the list
        If Me.tbxNote.Text = Mid(strUndoList(strUndoList.count), 13) Then 'the current text matches the most recent item in the Undo list, so, update the location info in the current strUdoList
            'remove the current item; it is added back below with the updated selection position
            strUndoList.Remove strUndoList.count
        Else  'if we have an Undo list and we are going to add a new item, clear the Redo list if it exists since adding a new item to the Undo list means the Redo list will no longer be valid
            If strRedoList.count > 0 Then  'Redo list exists
                Set strRedoList = New Collection  'clears all items from the old collection by setting it to a new empty collection
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    strUndoList.Add Format(Me.tbxNote.selStart, "00000") & "," & Format(Me.tbxNote.selLength, "00000") & "|" & Me.tbxNote.Text  'add selection start, selection length, and text note to the Undo list

    'limit size of Undo list to intMaxListCount; deleting the first item in the list will shift all items after it toward the beginning (so item 2 becomes item 1, item 3 becomes item 2, and so on until item 51 becomes item 50)
    If strUndoList.count > intMaxListCount Then strUndoList.Remove (1)
End Sub

Private Sub UndoIt()
    'this sub will replace the note text with the last undo value
    'if this was called from a button, then the .Text value will not be accessible
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name <> "tbxNote" Then Exit Sub 'we cannot process the .Text value of the note textbox control if the textbox does not have the focus
    
    If strUndoList.count > 0 Then  'check for existing undo items
        If Me.tbxNote.Text = Mid(strUndoList(strUndoList.count), 13) Then  'the current text in the note is equivalent to the most recent Undo item, so, delete the current Undo list item to get to the previous one which should be different
            If strUndoList.count = 1 Then  'there's only 1 item in the list, so we won't delete it, but neither will we put the text into the textbox since the text is already there
                Beep
                Exit Sub
            Else  'we have more than 1 item, so, since the most recent item = note text, delete the most recent item from the Undo list to get to the item the user presumably wants
                strUndoList.Remove strUndoList.count  'remove the last item in the list which is equal to the current text in the textbox, so cannot be the content the user was trying to revert to
            End If
        End If
    Else  'no undo items
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'the Undo item is ready to be restored to the note
    strRedoList.Add Format(Me.tbxNote.selStart, "00000") & "," & Format(Me.tbxNote.selLength, "00000") & "|" & Me.tbxNote.Text  'add current location+text before Undo to the Redo list in case the user changes their mind and wants to undo the Undo
    'update the textbox with the previous version of the note
    Me.tbxNote = Mid(strUndoList(strUndoList.count), 13)
    'position the cursor in the historic location and selection
    Me.tbxNote.selStart = Val(strUndoList(strUndoList.count))
    Me.tbxNote.selLength = Val(Mid(strUndoList(strUndoList.count), 7))
    
    'Remove the Undo item just implemented
    strUndoList.Remove strUndoList.count
    'limit size of Redo list to intMaxListCount; deleting the first item in the list will shift all items after it toward the beginning (so item 2 becomes item 1, item 3 becomes item 2, and so on until item 51 becomes item 50)
    If strRedoList.count > intMaxListCount Then strRedoList.Remove (1)
End Sub

Private Sub RedoIt()
    'this sub will replace the note text with the last redo value (i.e., it will progressively undo the most recent undo action)
    'if this was called from a button, then the .Text value will not be accessible
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name <> "tbxNote" Then  'we cannot process the .Text value of the note textbox control if the textbox does not have the focus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If strRedoList.count > 0 Then  'check for existing redo items
        If Me.tbxNote.Text = Mid(strRedoList(strRedoList.count), 13) Then  'the current text in the note is equivalent to the most recent Redo item, so, delete the current Redo list item to get to the previous one which should be different
            If strRedoList.count = 1 Then  'there's only 1 item in the list, so we won't delete it, but neither will we put the text into the textbox since the text is already there
                Beep
                Exit Sub
            Else  'we have more than 1 item, so, since the most recent item = note text, delete the most recent item from the Redo list to get to the item the user presumably want
                strRedoList.Remove strRedoList.count  'remove the last item in the list which is equal to the current text in the textbox, so cannot be the content the user was trying to revert to
            End If
        End If
    Else  'no redo items
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'the Redo item is ready to be restored to the note
    strUndoList.Add Format(Me.tbxNote.selStart, "00000") & "," & Format(Me.tbxNote.selLength, "00000") & "|" & Me.tbxNote.Text  'add current location+text to the Undo list in case the user want to undo the redo
    Me.tbxNote = Mid(strRedoList(strRedoList.count), 13)  'update the textbox to the previous version
    'position the cursor in the historic location and selection
    Me.tbxNote.selStart = Val(strRedoList(strRedoList.count))
    Me.tbxNote.selLength = Val(Mid(strRedoList(strRedoList.count), 7))
    'remove the version just implemented
    strRedoList.Remove strRedoList.count
    'limit size of Undo list to intMaxListCount; deleting the first item in the list will shift all items after it toward the beginning (so item 2 becomes item 1, item 3 becomes item 2, and so on until item 51 becomes item 50)
    If strUndoList.count > intMaxListCount Then strUndoList.Remove (1)
End Sub

Hope this helps someone get better CTRL+Z/CTRL+Y functionality in MS Access!

Very interesting, thanks for the code and the extended documentation. For better re-usability I would perhaps not hardcode Me.tbxNote but use a module-wide textbox variable instead. -- Did you experiment with some sort of Timer (or time measuring) algorithm? E.g. if the user types a word, then decides against it, and taps Backspace n times (instead of holding Backspace), they will get n Undo states.

Thanks for the feedback, @Andre. Good idea for a module-wide textbox variable. I'll admit I'm not well-versed in using that approach, so I'll leave it to someone else to improve the code and add that enhancement. It's a great idea.
No, I did not experiment with a Timer. I'm already using the Timer for other functionality, and, I wanted Undo code that worked more like MS Word, which seems to function on the basis of chunks of text rather than a timer. I personally prefer a chunks-of-text approach because that's how I think about what I want to Undo--by text chunks, not amount of time.
